# Algorithm to compare two arrays of element and find most similar pairs efficiently

Tags: algorithm, string-comparison

I have two arrays of string of length `m` and `n` respectively, where the strings inside are all with length `x`, and I want to find the best matching pairs that contain the most number of common letter possible:

In a simple case, just consider these two strings

```
Sm = [AAAA, BBBB]
Sn = [ABBA, AAAA, AAAA, CCCC]
```

**Expected results (2 pairs matched, 2 strings left alone):**

Pair 1: `AAAA` -> `AAAA` because of score 4

Pair 2: `BBBB` -> `ABBA` because of score 2

Strings in `Sn` that are left alone:

1. `AAAA` because the same string in `Sm` has been matched already
2. `CCCC` because unable to match any

**Score matrix:**

[image: Score matrix]

**My current method (Slow):**

1. Get the string length `x`, which is the max score (the case where all letters are identical) - in this case it is `4`
2. Brute force compare `m`x`n` times generate the score matrix above - in this case it is `2*4` times
3. Loop from `x` to `1`: (In this case it is looping from `4` to `1`)

   - Walk through the score matrix and pop the string pairs with score `x`
4. Mark remaining unpaired strings or strings with `0` score as alone

**Question:**

My current method is slow with O(mn) when producing the score matrix (`x` will not be large so I assume const here).
Is there any algorithm that can perform better than O(mn) complexity?

Comment: May i know why the downvote please?

Comment: Updated the title. It is actually more related to array comparison than string comparison.

Comment: How many different symbol/letters used in the string 255? 26? 3?  Max length of string?  How big may `x` be?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In fact I was trying to compare 2 csv files but in this case I just simplified the case to individual alphabets. Let’s assume the letters to be alphanumeric only and x to be 100 at max, what will the strategy be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't yet have enough rep to simply provide a comment but in a project I wrote a long time ago I leveraged the [Levenshtien Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.  Specifically see [this](https://github.com/DanHarltey/Fastenshtein) project for some helpful insight.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong @Mk Yung, but this question can basically be boiled down to comparing the elements of two arrays, rather than the specific comparison algorithm being used. So while Levenshtien's Distance algorithm is very useful for computing the actual distance, it would not bring the complexity of the total comparison algortihm to be below )(mn)

Comment: I agree that this answer doesn't solve the O(mn) complexity however a different matching algorithm may still help.  Unfortunately we haven't been provided with upper bounds.  @MK Yung, just how big can n, m, and x be?

Comment: @joshmeranda correct - maybe i am giving a misleading title. Let me update it.

Comment: @DavidCross m and n can be up to 100k while x is less than 100

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are doing the most efficient thing. To be completely thorough you need to compare every string in Sn with every string in Sn, so at best the algorithm will be O(mn). Anything less would not be comparing every element to every element.

One optimization could be to remove all duplicates, but that would for the most part incur a performance hit that would likely cause more harm than good in almost all circumstances.